# Visual Studio debugger goes wrong on this C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4), I've created a console application using .NET 4.5.2. Here's the C# code that demonstrates the problem. If I put a breakpoint on the switch statement and debug (with Debug build configuration), it steps through the case statement, but after the break statement instead of stepping after the switch statement, the debugger steps to the throw exception statement, although this code doesn't actually run, no exception is thrown. If I make any change - make it not async, change the code in the case statement or the default statement, then it works ok. Is this a bug in the debugger?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            DoSomethingAsync(1).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(int number)
        {
            switch (number)
            {
                case 1:
                    var encodedPayload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc");
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new Exception("Shouldn't get here!");
            }

            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be more inclined to think there is a discrepancy between the debug symbols (your compiled code) and the source code. Do a Clean on the solution and rebuild the solution to verify

Comment: Agree, also make sure you are running in Debug Mode with Code Optimizations turned off (Project properties -> Build -> Optimize code checkbox)

Comment: The problem is just because of the heavy rewriting of the IL that the `async` keyword introduces. Some code is shared for the prologue of the `MoveNext` method that is being generated, shared between the various parts of the method *that can exit*. Unfortunately the rewriting logic doesn't get the debugging information 100% correct so the debugger is actually correct, it is following the debug information that matches the instruction pointer, but the debugging information is wrong, or incomplete, and doesn't line up with the source code neatly any more.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce, Clean doesn't help and it's a default Debug config with no optimization. The linked question seems to be the same problem, thanks.